# Console Application Icon not displaying when running from a different folder (Windows)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, cmd, icons

I have a c++ application with an rc file that specifies a particular icon.

When I run it by double clicking on it or from a batch file or console like this:

```
start program.exe
```

(start in order to create a new window for it), the icon is displayed correctly for the new window.

However, if I'm not at the same folder and I do:

```
start folder\program.exe
```

The new window has instead the default windows application icon.

Why does this happen? I have checked with other console applications like Lua and it doesn't happen for them.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Wild guess: Does your application contain a manifest file (standalone or embedded) that specifies the icon file using a relative path name?

Comment: No, I only specify the icon in a rc file and it gets embedded in the exe. If I make a copy of the exe inside the current directory and run the one in the other folder then it also finds the icon. So windows is trying to find the icon in the working directory.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but would like to provide additional info: the command `start folder\program.exe` will use the custom icon if you simply have a copy of your `program.exe` in the current folder!

Comment: Yes, I have also seen that now. And if the exe is found on any of the folders on the PATH variable it will work as well. One weird but interesting thing is that putting the .ico file on the same folder won't work, but if it's renamed to have the ".exe" extension it will ("program.exe" which really is an icon). Finally I have checked the i/o operations with Process Explorer and windows seems to try to search in the working directory and on the folders contained in the PATH

Comment: Sounds like the OS is simply trying to be helpful, and display the icon if it can find it. Icons are really meant for use with GUIs, not the command line. Maybe this is just something you have to live with.